# How to apply two different functions to one column if meets the condition?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I need to apply 2 different functions to 1 columns if it meets a condition. My dataframe looks like this. I want to apply the functions to the column produce: veg_pro if the category is a vegetable and fruit_pro if it's a fruit.

```
Produce            Category
apple is good      fruit
corn is bad        vegetable
beans is good      vegetable
grape if good      fruit
```

My functions look like this:

```
def veg_pro(text):
    reg_tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer('\s+', gaps = True)
    terms = reg_tokenizer.tokenize(text) 
    return terms

def fruit_pro(text):
    reg_tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(“[\w+.]+“)
    terms = reg_tokenizer.tokenize(text) 
    return terms

 df['produce']= df['produce'].apply(lambda x: 
 veg_pro(x) if df['Category'] =='vegetable’ else 
 fruit_pro(x))
    
 ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use 
 a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using `apply` on one `column` use it on the `dataframe` like this:

```
 df['produce']= df.apply(lambda x: 
 veg_pro(x["produce"]) if x["Category"] =="vegetable" else fruit_pro(x["produce"]),axis=1)
```